# i want to show all data from the database for this table AddressBook in mvc4 with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC or MVC4 and also Entity Framework so i hope your help .

I have like this entity class :

```
 public class AddressBook
    {
        public AddressBook()
        {
            this.AddressBookItems = new List<AddressBookItem>();

        }
        public int AddressBookId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required]
        public string AddressBookName { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AddressBookItem> AddressBookItems { get; set; }
    }
```

now i want to show all data from the database for this table AddressBook
The table must contain the following column on the font side:

#### User | AddressBookName |

Please help me .
i can show the AddressBookName but this table contain the userId , so i cant show the user name into the list .

Comment: "*on the font side*" - you mean client side, surely? Also, show what code you currently have and why it's not working.

Comment: you should probably try some EF and/or MVC tutorials. Some cover both topics at once.  Much better than asking an open ended question here that is the first step of a journey.